# Get Type by Name

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5

In my code I am trying to get a type by name. When I was using a string argument I failed. Then I have tried to do the follwing in the Quick watch window:

```
Type.GetType(typeof(System.ServiceModel.NetNamedPipeBinding).Name)
```

returns null. Why? and how to get the desired type by name?

Comment: Whats wrong with just `typeof(System.ServiceModel.NetNamedPipeBinding)`

Comment: The question is about how to do it by a type name...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Type.GetType` can only find types in `mscorlib` or current assembly when you pass namespace qualified name. To make it work you need "AssemblyQualifiedName".

> The assembly-qualified name of the type to get. See
>   AssemblyQualifiedName. If the type is in the currently executing
>   assembly or in Mscorlib.dll, it is sufficient to supply the type name
>   qualified by its namespace.

Referece [Type.GetType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

`System.ServiceModel.NetNamedPipeBinding` lives in "System.ServiceModel.dll" hence `Type.GetType` can't find it.

This will work

```
Type.GetType(typeof(System.ServiceModel.NetNamedPipeBinding).AssemblyQualifiedName)
```

Or if you know the assembly already use following code

```
assemblyOfThatType.GetType(fullName);//This just need namespace.TypeName
```

Comment: you are right. thanks! can you give me any ideas about getting to AssemblyQualifiedName from the type name? or how can I get an instnace of NetNamedPipeBinding by name "NetNamedPipeBinding". Initial idea was  Activator.CreateInstance(myType); where my type was a correct type

Comment: Atleast do you know which assembly type lives in?

Comment: Check my update if that helps.. to get assembly instance use typeof(AnyTypeFromServiceModelAssembly).Assembly

Comment: I wish they will make it more clear what are the consequences of doing this one, as it will not try to load it from your app domain, but instead will try to read it directly from the dll.

Answer (score 15):

If you want use simple name (not AssemblyQualifiedName), and don't worry about ambiguous, you can try something like this:

```
    public static Type ByName(string name)
    {
        foreach (var assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Reverse())
        {
            var tt = assembly.GetType(name);
            if (tt != null)
            {
                return tt;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Reverse() - for load most recently loaded type (for example after compilation of code from aspx)

Comment: Wow! this is a solution for all possible cases :). but in my case assemblyOfThatType.GetType(fullName) was enough!

Answer (score 4):

Based on Vladimir's answer here is a LINQ version with the optional part of falling back to the first partial result *if* no exact match found:

```
private static Type ByName(string name)
{
    return
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
            .Reverse()
            .Select(assembly => assembly.GetType(name))
            .FirstOrDefault(t => t != null)
        // Safely delete the following part
        // if you do not want fall back to first partial result
        ??
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
            .Reverse()
            .SelectMany(assembly => assembly.GetTypes())
            .FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name.Contains(name));
}
```

Comment: This is cool. I just modified this method by putting it in a static By class. The code looks pretty then, By.Name("IWhatEverService"); Thanks! I needed this for targeting a dependency registered from another project I couldn't reference.

Answer (score 0):

.Name gives you NetNamedPipeBinding, for GetType to work you'll need full assembly name (AssemblyQualifiedName)

Answer (score 0):

The other answers almost have it right. To load a type by name, you either need it's full name (if the assembly has already been loaded into the appdomain) or its Assembly Qualified name.

The full name is the type's name, including the namespace. You can get that by calling `Type.GetType(typeof(System.ServiceModel.NetNamedPipeBinding).FullName)`. In your contrived example, this will work (since `NetNamedPipeBinding`'s assembly is assured to be loaded).

If you can't be sure it's loaded, use Sriram's answer, and pass a full assembly qualified name (TopNamespace.SubNameSpace.ContainingClass, **MyAssembly**). This will have .NET try to find and load htat assembly, then get the type.