# C# Create a class with name of dynamic string

Tags: c#, class, dynamic

Is it possible to create a class which does not exist with specific name from a dynamic string. I'm asking this because I want to create a class based on some string result.

If it is possible please share some example or some reference link.

I see that my question is confusing, so here is more clarification:

Assume that I have a method/function/procedure which returns a string - MyNewClassName(). I want to create a class with name equal to the result of MyNewClassName(), which is dynamic and also it is a custom name.

**EDIT** from comment
I'll use it as some kind of debugging, because I'm trying to fix some exception remotely, the problem is that the system does not provide the exception message only the type of the exception. So my idea is to create custom exception named with the result of the actual exception.

Comment: Why do you need a dynamicly named class? - and how would you reference it in your code?

Comment: you mean class or instance of a class ?

Comment: Take a look at System.Reflection, System.CodeDom.Compiler and Microsoft.CSharp.

Comment: @Sriram Sakthivel: I want to create a class dynamically not an instance of a class. I think that all answers below are related to creating of an instance of a class.

Comment: @Jens Kloster: That's why am I asking about it, because I'm not aware if this is possible. It seems not to be a common practice if it is possible.

Comment: @nenito I dont think it *is* possible. I was curious about your requirment for wanting a dynamicly named class :) and how you intended to use it in your code

Comment: Post some sample string. and you can compile a DLL or Exe, It is not clear what you meant by create a class?

Comment: @Jens Kloster: I'll use it as some kind of debugging, because I'm trying to fix some exception remotely, the problem is that the system does not provide the exception message only the type of the exception. So my idea is to create custom exception named with the result of the actual exception.

Comment: See for instance http://stackoverflow.com/q/3862226/121309

Comment: @nenito ok :) I think you should mention that in your question - becuase a better solution (than dynamic creating a class) might be found.

Comment: @Hans Kesting: Vielen Dank!!

Comment: Few weeks ago I've participated to a lecture about JVM & opcodes, now it seems that this is related to the same, but concerning C#. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you have the classes assembly qualified full name in a string (obtained from whereever, the user can type it in or something), you can do the following:

```
var name = "MyNameSpace.MyType, MyAssembly";
var type = Type.GetType(name);
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

This assumes the assembly you specify is already loaded.

Comment: Dear anonymous downvoter, please leave a comment, if you don't, I cannot improve my post.

Comment: Sure.. This won't work unless and until you have assembly qualified name, or (type exist in mscorlib/current assembly). And question is not clear though.

Comment: FYI I've answered it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20008602/2530848)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel You are right, I edited my answer.

Comment: I removed my downvote.. +1..

Answer (score 1):

You can get an instance of a type by using `Activator.CreateInstance(type)` . for getting type by type name see here: [Get Type by Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20008503/get-type-by-name)

Comment: Oh man.. +1 for referring my answer.. But if you feel question is duplicate, vote to close.. or flag it.. That's what am going to do..