# Convert List<object> to List<model> type with only the model name c# mvc

Tags: c#, object, types, casting, typeof

So I'm trying to create a generic function (currently it's not but I wanted to future proof it, so in a later stage the tableName can be picked/passed through).

I want to use the string `Customers_Model` to get the model and for the variable `c` to be of type `Customers_Model` but I keep getting type `object`.

I know that you can do:
`(Customers_Model)Activator.CreateInstance(type)`
but that assumes that you know that model type but I've only got the model type from a string. I feel as if there's something to do with the `type` variable as it contains the model name but can't quite put my finger on it.

I've also seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12234122/10169277) but it assumes that you know of a function that you want to access within your model. In this case we don't know any functions/fields within there to use this solution only the `modelName`.

```
        public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
        {
            var tableName = "Customers";
            string modelName = "MVC.Models." + tableName + "_Model";
            Type type = Type.GetType(modelName);
            var d = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            var c = Convert.ChangeType(d, type);
            var data = await DBServices.GetFromTable(tableName, c);
            if (data.Count > 0)
            {
                return View(data);
            }
            else 
                return View();
        }
```

**EDIT 1**

I would like for the user to pick a table and then have it display the table in the View. My View accepts a model `GeneralViewModel`

GeneralViewModel:

```
    public class GeneralViewModel
    {
        public List<Customers_Model> Customers {get; set;}
    }
```

At a later stage I would like to be able to add in more models to this and not have to change the controller/View as it's been generalised.

Should I instead convert `c` to a `GeneralViewModel` instead and when it's displaying in the view then to just look for the first List where the count > 0 and to diplay that? I only expect one list in `GeneralViewModel` to be populated at a time.

**EDIT 2**

Here's a couple of functions from my DBServices because that the T type being sent in is object (due to var c above) then the return type is object aswell. If I can just sort out the type being passed in then this will all be resolved.

```
        public static async Task<List<T>> GetFromTable<T>(string tableName, T type)
        {
            var results = new List<T>();
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                string cmdText = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName + ";";

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn);
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    SqlDataReader reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        if (reader != null)
                        {
                            results.Add(ConvertReader((IDataReader)reader, type));
                        }
                    }
                    reader.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }
            return results;
        }

        public static T ConvertReader<T>(IDataReader reader, T value)
        {
            //var item = value;
            var typeProperties = value.GetType().GetProperties();

            foreach (var property in typeProperties)
            {
                DisplayNameAttribute attr = (DisplayNameAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(property, typeof(DisplayNameAttribute));

                int ordinal;
                if (attr != null)
                {
                    ordinal = reader.GetOrdinal(attr.DisplayName);
                }
                else
                {
                    ordinal = reader.GetOrdinal(property.Name);
                }

                if (!reader.IsDBNull(ordinal))
                {
                    property.SetValue(value, reader[ordinal], null);
                }
            }

            return value;
        }
```

Comment: `Convert.ChangeType` is useless here, as it returns an `object`, just as `Activator.CreateInstance` does. But even if you manage to convert the data to a strongly typed list, how will you pass it to the correct methods down the line? Note that generic types always resolved at compile time. They are not helpful at all in dynamic scenarios. just work against the non-generic `IList` interface.

Comment: What is the *actual* problem you are trying to solve? Generic is a compile time concept in C#, if you define your table name at runtime you are looking for "Reflection", and while that is sometimes useful, it often becomes an unreadable mess that is difficult to maintain. By chance, "Future proof" is sometimes also used for unreadable code that is difficult to maintain.

Comment: If you want to get a type by its name, you may use `Type.GetType`, as shown here for instance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20008503/get-type-by-name. However as JonasH mentioned, you will *never* get anything different than `object` using reflection, you need to cast to the *compile-time* type, which makes the entire thing pretty pointless.

Comment: Can you extract a common interface all your entities implement?

Comment: Nope I cannot. They've all got different fields within them and at compile time I wouldn't know what table the user is picking and so I don't know what fields would be available

Comment: When you call `var d = Activator.CreateInstance(type)` you get an object that ***is an instance of `type`*** but at run-time you only get a reference to it as an `object`. There is no sense trying to then convert it to a type of `type` as it already is that type.

Comment: So then should I just change my GeneralViewModel to:

`    public class GeneralViewModel
    {
        public List<object> Customers {get; set;}
    }`?

Comment: Strong Typisation is your friend. See the PHP and JavaScript examples on why you should be happy to have it: http://www.sandraandwoo.com/2015/12/24/0747-melodys-guide-to-programming-languages/ | Any chance this is a MVVM model project? Because all you need for that would be a class Heirarchy with a subclass for each table, and some Type Targetting view Templates on the view side.

Comment: It's a MVC project. Any chance you could expand or send a link with an example on what you've mentioned in the later half?

Comment: @Manib - No, you'd use LINQ to convert your `List<object>` to a `List<Customer_Model>`. I don't see if your code when you are getting a `List<object>` so I can't comment how you'd do that?

Comment: @Manib Sorry, I do not know MVC enough to help here. But I think a good starting point would be to make a Class Heirarchy: Starting 'abstract baseTable'. Then use that as the base type of your collections. Each table will need their own database query, as each needs to map the query results to it's own fields. And the View then has to sort out how to display each specific instance.

Comment: Much appreciated @Christopher. I've just edited the question (EDIT 2) with the code I use to get the data from the DB. It's quite generic.

Comment: @Enigmativity please see EDIT 2

Comment: @Manib I do not know MVC anywhere near enough to give actual code or even evaluate it. | However one pet peeve of mine is exception handling and I saw you do not let fatal exceptions go on. That is a big mistake in exception handling. I have two articles on the topic I like to link often: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/vexing-exceptions | https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET

Comment: Much appreciated for the advice I'll take a look at it at a later stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just creating a `Dictionary<string, dynamic>` which I used to convert the string to the model type. I then passed that into the `GetFromTable` function as the second parameter. It then returned the right results.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with pattern matching?

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Globalization;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Reflection;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            List<int> a = GetList(10, 10);
            List<double> b = GetList(10, 100.0);
            List<ModelTest> c = GetList(10, new ModelTest());
           
        }

        private static List<T> GetList<T>(int numberOfElements, T value)
        {
            Type type = typeof(T);

            var actualInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

            actualInstance = value;

            var list = new List<T>();

            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++)
            {
                if (actualInstance is T t)
                {
                    list.Add(t);
                }
            }

            return list;
        }

    }
    internal class ModelTest
    {
       public ModelTest()
       {

       }
    }
}
```

This compiles and returns the expected result, that is a simple example, there are still things to add, if the type `T` does not contain a parameterless constructor it will bring an exception, of course you can avoid that improving the `GetList()` method.

Is it what you need?, Am I missing something here?

Regards

Miguel :)